# Unicode working in PHP

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8

Can someone explain why all this code works normally if PHP is only supposed to support a 256-character set?

I know that Content-Type tag interpret these characters if is on UTF-8.
But why PHP work it?

```
echo "匝";

if (preg_match('/啊/', "啊"))
    echo "Match";

if (preg_match('/\w/', "啊"))
    echo "Match";
```

Comment: Does your PHP configuration have the `mbstring` (multibyte string) extension enabled?

Comment: one line says  ;mbstring.strict_encoding = Off i dont know if the one that you are talking about

Comment: Where is the reference that says PHP only supports 256 character set?  Never mind, found it, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: It seems that exist packages to support 256 up characters but not much info. i think.

Comment: @nEAnnam: The semicolon is key -- it's a comment, so your parameter is "not off".

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Uncommented and still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare your code to:

```
if (preg_match('/^\w$/', "啊"))
    echo "Match";
```

regex `/\w/` works because your multibyte char contains of 2 bytes: 0x53 and 0x1D. And first one, 0x53 looks like a valid single-byte char `S`

PS: this is valid way to match one multibyte letter:

```
var_dump(preg_match('/^\p{L}$/u', "匝", $matches));
```

Comment: So its not handling the character? its handle the bytes? why can be echoed? at the first sentence

Comment: @nEAnnam: it handles characters, supposing each char is single byte. Cannot get all your questions... It can be echoed - because you echo it.

Comment: lol, sorry yeah im thinking that its so useful your answer, ill compare  a single byte from the char with the entire character

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that your PCRE has been compiled with Unicode support enabled (`--enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties`) which would cause preg_match() to match unicode characters.